# Existence of a function from a quotient

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra, quotient-set

On "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" by John M. Lee, at page 309 we're talking about multilinear algebra. There's a proposition on the Characteristic Property of the Tensor Product Space. In the proof he says: "The fact that $A$ is multilinear
means precisely that the subspace $R$ is contained in the kernel of $\bar{A}$" and so "Therefore, $\bar{A}$ descends to a linear map $\tilde{A}$". How $R \subseteq ker\bar{A}$ justifies the existence of the map $\tilde{A}$. Also speaking at set level is it right to say that (in this particular case) $${X\over ker \bar{A} }\subseteq {X\over R} $$ if $R \subseteq ker \bar{A}$, thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at Exercise B.15(b) in Appendix B of ISM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is a much more general fact about "quotients", but I will keep to the setting of linear algebra.

Let $A:V\to W$ be a linear map between two vector spaces. Also let $R\subset V$ be a subspace, so that we can form the quotient vector space $V/R = \{v+R:v\in V\}$, where $v+R = v+r+R$ whenever $r\in R$.

If $\ker A$ contains $R$, then we can define $$\tilde A(v+R):= A(v).$$
**This is well defined because** if $r\in R$, then $$\tilde A((v+r)+R) = A(v+r) = A(v) +A(r) = A(v)= \tilde A(v+R).$$

I'm not sure what you mean by the "quotient of sets" you have written there. One fact which may help your intuition is that if $\ker A$ contains the subspace $R$ (so $\ker A$ is "bigger"), then we will have $$\dim (V/\ker A) \leq \dim (V/R)$$
("dividing by a bigger thing gives a smaller thing")

Comment: "dividing by a bigger thing gives a smaller thing", it was exactly what I was thinking and it was confusing me a little. Your explanation it's crystal clear. What I mean by quotient set, it's the set formed by all the equivalences classes given an equivalence relation. I think it is replicable what you've done.